# Mail server, why there is need in smtp.mail.com or imap.mail.com or mail.mail.com

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I'm trying to understand why we need this subdomains ?

```
(smtp.mail.com or imap.mail.com or mail.mail.com)
```

Do they point to same `IP` ? If yes why not to use `FQDN` ?

Or they point to a different `IP` ? when you need to implement this?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP and IMAP are two different protocols, usually implemented by two different server software systems.  On smaller deployments, they are often hosted on the same server, in which case the names are redundant.

On much larger deployments (say `gmail` or `yahoo`), they are hosted on separate servers, or sometimes on separate groups of servers, using multi-record DNS or a load balancer or even more exotic systems.